# Как объяснить тире в сложном предложении?

Tags: грамматика, тире, сложное-предложение, пункуация

Из современной художественной литературы:

*Николас никогда не видел, чтобы человек моментально делался белым, как мел, – **он всегда полагал, что это выражение относится к области метафористики,** однако же проводник действительно вдруг стал совсем белым, даже губы приобрели светло-серый оттенок, а глаза заморгали часто-часто.*

Правильно выбраны знаки? Какая это **грамматика**? Как можно объяснить постановку **тире?** Возможна ли здесь **вставная конструкция?**